# PL/SQL error LPX-00249 while parsing XML file from web

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, xml-parsing

I'm writing a programm in PL/SQL for downloading XML files from internet, parsing them and storing values in Oracle database. I have one large XML file, which includes links for a huge amount of smaller XMLs. There are about 6253 files to be parsed. I have function, which downloads XML file into CLOB and saves data into XmlType. This value is returned into programm and is further processed. This is the function:

```
create or replace function get_xml_by_url
( v_url VARCHAR2
) 
RETURN XMLType  
AS
  req      SYS.UTL_HTTP.REQ;
  resp     SYS.UTL_HTTP.RESP;
  xmlClob  CLOB;
  x        XmlType;
  l_offset number := 1;
  value    VARCHAR2(3999);  -- URL to post to
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    UTL_HTTP.SET_PROXY('http://10.1.250.233:8080');
    req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST (url=> v_url, method => 'GET');
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER
    ( r      =>  req
    , name   =>  'Content-Type'
    , value  =>  'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
    );
    resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xmlClob, true);

    -- Loading first line
    UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(resp,value,false);
    DBMS_LOB.WRITE(xmlClob,length(value),l_offset,value);
    l_offset := l_offset + length(value);

    -- Loading and adjusting second line
    UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(resp,value,true);
    value := rtrim(value,'xmlns="http://seznam.gov.cz/ovm/datafile/seznamovm/v1">')||'>';
    DBMS_LOB.WRITE(xmlClob, length(value), l_offset,value);
    l_offset := l_offset + length(value);

    -- Filling CLOB
    LOOP
      UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(resp,value,false);
      DBMS_LOB.WRITE(xmlClob,length(value),l_offset,value);
      l_offset := l_offset + length(value);
    END LOOP;

  EXCEPTION
    when UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY 
    then
      UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
    when others 
    then
      utl_http.end_response(resp);  
  END;
  x := XMLType.createXML(xmlClob);
  DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(xmlClob);  
  RETURN x;
END;
```

I was calling this function in a loop for all 6.253 XMl files and every time I've got an error, but every time in different file, and when I ran the script again for only the one XML file which raised an error, it ran fine. I think that the problem is something about memory, but I don't know where a nd why it occurs.
I'm getting following error:

```
Error report:
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00249: invalid external ID declaration
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: in "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 5
ORA-06512: in "GET_XML_BY_URL", line 47
ORA-06512: in line 29
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

GET_XML_BY_URL is a name given to described function. Does anybody have any experience wuth this kind of problem?
Best regards, Michal

Comment: Have you tried setting the cache parameter for dbms_lob.createtemporary() to false?

Comment: do you think it could help? I thought that it's needed for clob and its freed in the end of function

Comment: it fell after 45 seconds with LPX-00007 error

Comment: I have another set of XML files -- it has only 140 files. For this set, programm runs fine

Comment: Something is missing in the code example. Please add. Please add also XML file that reproduces issue. From my experience, it is probably an issue with namespace/DTD.

Comment: My code looks exactly like I posted it here. Nothing is missing in 
value:=rtrim(value,'xmlns="http://seznam.gov.cz/ovm/datafile/seznamovm/v1">')||'>';
XML file reproducing issue is different every time I run it. When I ran function only on the file that reproduced error last time, it ran fine. I'm executing function on files located on addresses http://seznam.gov.cz/ovm/datafile.do?format=xml&service=seznamovm in element Dokument//Subjekt//DetailSubjektu . Last time I ran the function it failed on http://seznam.gov.cz/ovm/datafile.do?format=xml&service=seznamovm&id=Nenacovice

Comment: Now I know, that this function fails only on two files. http://seznam.gov.cz/ovm/datafile.do?format=xml&service=seznamovm&id=NEZDICE and http://seznam.gov.cz/ovm/datafile.do?format=xml&service=seznamovm&id=VYSSIBROD . Other 6 251 files are fine.